# Revision Change Summary using SpreadSheet API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to compare two revisions of a spreadsheet using spreadsheet API and find the change summary?

Regards
Pravin B

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drive API to retrieve the list of revisions for any document (including a spreadsheet) and fetch the content of each revision:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-revisions